# Wedge product of $0$-forms?

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Given a manifold $M$, and a $0$-form $f$ and a $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$ for $k>0$, it is standard to define $f \wedge \omega$ as simply $f\omega$, where $\bigwedge^k T^*M$ is being considered as a module over $\bigwedge^0 T^*M:=\mathrm{C}^\infty(M)$ in the natural way. My question is very simple: how can one extend this definition to the case where $k=0$ in a consistent way?

Comment: What definition/construction of the wedge product are you using?

Comment: We can just define it as $\omega \wedge \rho : = \omega \otimes \rho - \rho \otimes \omega$ up to some normalization constant.

Answer (score 1):

The (wedge) product of two zero forms that is of two functions $f,g$ is just $fg$.

Comment: I think the op is asking why this definition is consistent with the properties of the wedge product, rather than the asking for the definition itself.

Comment: Indeed, Bernard. By this definition, the wedge product is not antisymmetric, among other issues.

Comment: @Bernard what means "how can one extend this definition" for you?

Comment: @Archaick: Sure it is. Antisymmetric means $\omega\wedge\eta = (-1)^{k\ell} \eta\wedge\omega$, when $\omega\in\Omega^k$ and $\eta\in\Omega^\ell$. So, when $k=\ell=0$, we have ...

Comment: @Ted Shifrin *Face slap*. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An observation that helps to understand the case $k=0$ is the fact that $0$-multilinear forms on a vector space $\mathbb V$ over $\mathbb R$ are scalar functions
$$
   f\colon\mathbb V^{\otimes^0}\to\mathbb R
$$
with no restrictions imposed on them (there is no coordinate where to impose linearity). Since $\mathbb V^{\otimes^0}=\{0_{\mathbb V}\}$, we conclude that $0$-multilinear forms can be identified with constants because:
$$
   \mathbb R^{\{0_{\mathbb V}\}} \cong \mathbb R.
$$
Since constants are also alternating $0$-multiforms, we deduce that
$$
   \Lambda^0(X)=\coprod_{p\in X}\mathbb R = X\times\mathbb R.
$$
Therefore, every section $\omega\colon X\to X\times\mathbb R$ of the projection $\pi\colon X\times\mathbb R\to X$, onto the first coordinate, can be identified with its projection onto the second coordinate, i.e., with a function from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Thus, the imposition of smoothness on $0$-forms defined on $X$ coincides with the smoothness of scalar functions defined on $X$.